# Common name for index for lexicographical sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, terminology

Is there some common name for index for lexicographical sorting?

I have text and index to it sorted by lexicographical order of all substrings which start from specific position and last till the end of the text.

Let's consider the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

auto make_index_projection_for_subrange = []<std::ranges::random_access_range R>(R & range) {
    return [&range](std::ranges::range_difference_t<R> i) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::begin(range)+i, std::ranges::end(range));
        };
};

int main()
{
    const std::string s1 = "abdbc";
    std::vector i1{0,1,2,3,4};
    
    //Sort by substring from the char to the end
    auto proj = make_index_projection_for_subrange(s1);

    std::ranges::sort(i1, std::ranges::lexicographical_compare,proj);
    std::ranges::copy(i1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(auto i: i1){
        std::cout << std::string(s1.begin()+i, s1.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c644fq3qo); it provides the following results:

> 03142
> abdbc
> bc
> bdbc
> c
> dbc

All the substrings are now sorted alphabetically and search as fast as at least binary search. If one need to find similar strings, this is just passing through adjacent lines.

I call this "adjacent index" because all similar substrings are adjacent to each other, but I guess this this is a classic structure with a common name.

Comment: *"Another question"*: a question on Stack Overflow should be one question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: *Maybe* a trie.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, thank you so much! Of course, suffixes! It is strange how I missed this while in many places of code I have names like "suffix", etc. If you like, post as the answer so that I could accept it formally. Feel free to ignore the second part of the question, which starts with "Another question...", I will separate it into another question, I *trincot* suggested.

Comment: @sweenish, formally I don't have an explicit tree here and don't have links between nodes marked by characters, but anyway implicitly I see that this is close, since changing the representation one could come to another. Thank you for the clue, it helps, as well, but in this particular case the term *suffix array* is exactly what I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is [Suffix_array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

While the [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is closely related and could be helpful, as well.

(Just to have it formally answered and easier to find the answer, based on the comments above)